# Infinite redirect with Wordpress proxied from Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy, wordpress

We're trying to setup Apache on a public server to proxy requests to Apache with WordPress on another server, but we're getting infinite redirect loops.

Requests starting with www.example.com/about should get proxied to the internal server wp.example.corp. e.g.

```
www.example.com/about/about/team => proxy => wp.example.corp/about/team
```

To further complicate matters, our WordPress installation is in a subdirectory called "wp". So, on the WordPress server, we have the following settings:

- WordPress Address: http://www.example.com/about/wp
- Site Address: http://www.example.com/about

Here are some of the relevant bits from the Apache config on the public server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  #...
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyErrorOverride On
  <Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>


  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/about/?$
  RewriteRule ^/about/?$ http://wp.example.corp/ [P,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/about/.+
  RewriteRule ^/about/(.*) http://wp.example.corp/$1 [P,L]

  #...
</VirtualHost>
```

The Apache config on the WordPress server is pretty straightforward:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  #...
  DocumentRoot /var/lib/publicpages

  <Directory /var/lib/publicpages/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride FileInfo Indexes Limit Options
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is the .htaccess file from the root of the WordPress server:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

With LogLevel set to debug, I can see the requests hitting the public server and responding with 301 redirects:

```
x.x.x.x, y.y.y.y (y.y.y.y) - - [25/Jan/2012:16:44:28 -0600] "GET /about/about/team/ HTTP/1.1" 301 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2"
x.x.x.x, y.y.y.y (y.y.y.y) - - [25/Jan/2012:16:44:28 -0600] "GET /about/about/team/ HTTP/1.1" 301 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2"
```

And I can see the same requests hitting the WordPress server, who is responding with 301 redirects:

```
z.z.z.z - - [25/Jan/2012:16:44:28 -0600] "GET /about/team/ HTTP/1.1" 301 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2"
z.z.z.z - - [25/Jan/2012:16:44:29 -0600] "GET /about/team/ HTTP/1.1" 301 20 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2"
```

I also enabled full Rewrite logging on the WordPress server and see the following repeated over and over again:

```
x.x.x.x - - [26/Jan/2012:09:54:04 --0600] [www.example.com/sid#80e06c20][rid#80fa4200/initial] (3) [perdir /var/lib/publicpages/] add path info postfix: /var/lib/publicpages/about -> /var/lib/publicpages/about/team
x.x.x.x - - [26/Jan/2012:09:54:04 --0600] [www.example.com/sid#80e06c20][rid#80fa4200/initial] (3) [perdir /var/lib/publicpages/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/lib/publicpages/about/team -> about/team
x.x.x.x - - [26/Jan/2012:09:54:04 --0600] [www.example.com/sid#80e06c20][rid#80fa4200/initial] (3) [perdir /var/lib/publicpages/] applying pattern '^index\.php$' to uri 'about/team'
x.x.x.x - - [26/Jan/2012:09:54:04 --0600] [www.example.com/sid#80e06c20][rid#80fa4200/initial] (3) [perdir /var/lib/publicpages/] add path info postfix: /var/lib/publicpages/about -> /var/lib/publicpages/about/team
x.x.x.x - - [26/Jan/2012:09:54:04 --0600] [www.example.com/sid#80e06c20][rid#80fa4200/initial] (3) [perdir /var/lib/publicpages/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/lib/publicpages/about/team -> about/team
x.x.x.x - - [26/Jan/2012:09:54:04 --0600] [www.example.com/sid#80e06c20][rid#80fa4200/initial] (3) [perdir /var/lib/publicpages/] applying pattern '.' to uri 'about/team'
x.x.x.x - - [26/Jan/2012:09:54:04 --0600] [www.example.com/sid#80e06c20][rid#80fa4200/initial] (4) [perdir /var/lib/publicpages/] RewriteCond: input='/var/lib/publicpages/about' pattern='!-f' => matched
x.x.x.x - - [26/Jan/2012:09:54:04 --0600] [www.example.com/sid#80e06c20][rid#80fa4200/initial] (4) [perdir /var/lib/publicpages/] RewriteCond: input='/var/lib/publicpages/about' pattern='!-d' => matched
x.x.x.x - - [26/Jan/2012:09:54:04 --0600] [www.example.com/sid#80e06c20][rid#80fa4200/initial] (2) [perdir /var/lib/publicpages/] rewrite 'about/team' -> 'index.php'
x.x.x.x - - [26/Jan/2012:09:54:04 --0600] [www.example.com/sid#80e06c20][rid#80fa4200/initial] (3) [perdir /var/lib/publicpages/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /var/lib/publicpages/index.php
x.x.x.x - - [26/Jan/2012:09:54:04 --0600] [www.example.com/sid#80e06c20][rid#80fa4200/initial] (2) [perdir /var/lib/publicpages/] trying to replace prefix /var/lib/publicpages/ with /
x.x.x.x - - [26/Jan/2012:09:54:04 --0600] [www.example.com/sid#80e06c20][rid#80fa4200/initial] (5) strip matching prefix: /var/lib/publicpages/index.php -> index.php
x.x.x.x - - [26/Jan/2012:09:54:04 --0600] [www.example.com/sid#80e06c20][rid#80fa4200/initial] (4) add subst prefix: index.php -> /index.php
x.x.x.x - - [26/Jan/2012:09:54:04 --0600] [www.example.com/sid#80e06c20][rid#80fa4200/initial] (1) [perdir /var/lib/publicpages/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Seems like the Wordpress application code may be sending that redirect, since the Apache configuration shouldn't be.  The one oddity I see is that your last `RewriteRule` should be `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` instead of `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]` - it's adding an extra slash, due to the `RewriteBase`.  But, I doubt that's the issue - capture the request headers and see what `Location:` is pointed to in the redirects?

Comment: Location is "-". Content-Location is "-". Host is "www.example.com". I also fixed the extra slash from the RewriteRule, but not luck.

Comment: That's.. very strange.  Well, let's narrow it down to either Apache or Wordpress - in its vhost config, set a `RewriteLog` location that Apache can write to and set `RewriteLogLevel 9` - if Apache's not doing anything crazy with the request, then we can be sure that Wordpress is the culprit and go from there.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I have updated my question with the RewriteLog output. Looks like Apache is behaving itself, at least to my eyes.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like exactly what it's supposed to be doing, and it's certainly not sending a redirect, so I think we're looking at Wordpress misbehaving.  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with it to be too helpful on that front..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We gave up and just made the URLs/paths match in both Apache servers. E.g.

```
www.example.com/about/about/team => proxy => wp.example.corp/about/about/team
```

While that doesn't exactly *fix* the issue, it effectively sidesteps the problem and eliminates the redundant 301 redirects.

Answer (score -1):

You could use ProxyPass to do this, instead of using a Rewrite rule.

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /about/ http://wp.example.corp/
ProxyPassReverse /about/ http://wp.example.corp/
```

Comment: I'm not sure why ProxyPass would be different - I believe it's functionally equivalent to using a Rewrite rule with a proxy. I *think* both use mod_proxy under the hood. That said, strangely enough, I can't get ProxyPass to work at all in this case.